# what does "The run procedure option is not allowed with member type RPGLE" mean?

Tags: rpg

What does "The run procedure option is not allowed with member type RPGLE" mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you edit your question to include an example of code that produces the error?

Comment: And where do you see that error?

Comment: on the bottom of members using pdm. i try to run the program. when i use opt 16.it give me this message. i think the program did not compile. i found an error of * rnf 0257 on seu edit.

Comment: 0001.00  WUEXAMP   IF   F   49        DISK                       
                                            
                                                                 
                                                                 
                                                                 
          
Form-Type entry for main procedure not valid or out of sequence.

Comment: what this error mean (A right parenthesis is expected but is not found). I have the right parenthesis in the code.0001.00                                        REF(*LIBL/GTCSTP CUSREC)

Comment: Using the STRSEU on the source-type of RPGLE causes the Editor to syntax-check.  The proper specification for RPGLE for an earlier comment is 'FWUEXAMP   IF   F   49        disk' where the first **F** denotes the Form-Type of an F-Spec [a File Specification]. The msg RNF0357 does not refer to a missing right paren; an RPGLE can not code as the first line of source _i.e. the '0001.00'_ as 'REF(...'. If help is required using the Source Entry Utility (SEU) or how to code ILE RPG fixed-format specifications, probably best to open a new topic explaining what is being attempted and difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

> what does "The run procedure option is not allowed with member type `RPGLE`" mean?

Apparently that is the error message identifier PDM0365 with first-level text "The Run Procedure option is not allowed with member type &1." from the Message File (MSGF) QUOMSGF in library QPDA.  In the second level text [visible after F1=Help is pressed with the cursor positioned on that message id, or in Display Message Description (DSPMSGD) for that message Id and message file] what is the cause and the recovery for the error condition is further explained; i.e. the assistance requested on this site, probably could have been resolved by asking that the system should provide the Help:

```
 Cause . . . . . :   You cannot run a procedure with this type.
 Recovery  . . . :   The following member types can be run as procedures: REXX,
   OCL36, BASP, BASP38.
```

With the replacement text for the replacement-variable &1 being `RPGLE`, the indication is that the option-16="Run Procedure" was issued against a member listed in the Work With Members Using PDM (WRKMBRPDM) feature, and the **TYPE** for the member was **RPGLE** instead of one of the listed as supported *member types* noted in the *Recovery* text.

Additionally, if under the heading **Opt** [the USEnglish abbreviation for Option] the F1=Help were pressed [instead of] where the option 16 was typed, the following *Help Text* would be presented that explains what are the options that can be specified and what each of the system-supplied *numeric* options will effect:

```
 Help                            Options - Help                         

 16=Run procedure                                                   
     Type 16 to run a source member with a member type of REXX,     
     OCL36, BASP, or BASP38.  If you try to run a member with a type
     that cannot be run, you receive an error message.  To run an   
     OCL36 procedure, the file name must be QS36PRC.  You can have  
     the member run in batch mode or interactively depending on what
     you specified in the Run in batch prompt on the Change Defaults
     display.
```

Therefore if a **Run** option is not an eligible task to perform against the member of type=RPGLE, perhaps review the other options for what they might provide.  Here are two, one conspicuous by specific mention of support for the type-RPGLE in the Option *help-text* and another much more subtle by only an allusion to types that reflect an **ILE** source type [with `[...]` denoting snipped content from that help]:

```
 [...]
 14=Compile                                                        
     Type 14 to compile one or more members.  The system creates an
     object based on the member being compiled.  The member is     
     compiled interactively or in batch mode, depending on what you
     have specified on the Change Defaults display.                

     The following member types can be compiled: [...]
     PLI38, PNLGRP, PRTF, PRTF38, QRY38, RMC, RPG, RPGLE, RPG36,   
     RPG38, RPT, RPT36, RPT38, SPADCT, SQLC, SQLCPP, SQLCBL,       
     [...]  

     When the programming development manager compiles a program
     [...]

 15=Create module                                             
     Type 15 to create a module object for an ILE source type.
 [...]
```

For the latter, to create a Module (*MOD) object versus to create a Bound Program (*PGM) from the **RPGLE** type which is a contraction of RPG and ILE, denoting that type as an *ILE source type*.

So instead of using Option-16, use either of Option-14 or Option-15 to compile the ILE RPG source into an executable [*PGM] or a linkable [*MOD] object.

Answer (score 0):

Option 16 (Run procedure) only applies to REXX procedures (and maybe some others). You can't use it to run an RPG/COBOL/C program. It MIGHT work to run a CL program, but I don't think so.

To run a program, either CALL it from the command line or create your own PDM option.

The SEU error may or may not be an error - SEU hasn't been kept up-to-date with all the new features of the RPGLE language. Remember that SEU is simply a source editor/validator.

If you were able to compile the RPG program (using PDM option 14 for CRTBNDRPG or option 15 for CRTRPGMOD followed by running the CRTPGM command) then the SEU 'problem' isn't a problem at all.